# Is a finite ring extension of a local ring within the quotient ring indecomposable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring that contains a non zero divisor and $Q(R)$ its total quotient ring. Let $S\subseteq Q(R)$ be a finite ring extension of $R$. Is $S$ an indecomposable $R$-module? At least if $\dim(R)=1$ ?

$S$ is isomorphic to an ideal in $R$ containing a non zero divisor, but in general such ideals need not be indecomposable as shown here: [Is every ideal containing a non zero divisor a indecomposable module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952037) Thanks.